# Laravel Error 419 Page Expired or not loading the page at all after Webhook setup on Github

Tags: php, laravel

After I set up a webhook from my github to my laravel website, one of the pages stopped working. (Control Panel)

If I delete the webhook from Github, the page starts working again.

The symptoms are either Error 419 Page Expired or the page doesn't load at all after trying to login.

Any clues? I am thinking it might be related to VerifyCsrfToken exceptions but I don't know how I would add github webhook in there.

[Image of Webhook in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPWiL.png)

Comment: Can you please show us the setup of the GitHub webhook?

Comment: sure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPWiL.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Vinny for showing the photo of the Github webhooks setup. To resolve your problem you will need to do the following three steps:

1. You need to select `APPLICATION/JSON` in the `Content-Type` option
   of Github Webhooks. As Laravel doesn't include VerifyCSRFToken
   middleware for the JSON.
2. Make sure you are using `api` middleware group. To do that you need to define this endpoint in the `api.php` **NOT** in `web.php`.
3. After you define you can confirm your endpoint by prefix with `/api` with your domain name and the path defined in your `api.php`

For more context, you can visit this documentation URL.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-groups

**Note: I would recommend using signature verification to avoid bad usage of your endpoint and webhook triggers. To do that you can follow this nice article.**

https://dev.to/ryan1/how-to-validate-github-webhooks-with-laravel-and-php-2he1

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the help and the tip! Doing the application/json did the trick! Great article on the subject, Google didn't take me there when I needed it! :)